# Converging integral $\int_1^\infty {\frac{\sqrt{x}\cos{x}}{x+2013}}dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I want to show that $$\int_1^\infty {\frac{\sqrt{x}\cos{x}}{x+2013}}dx$$ is converging. I tried $${\frac{\sqrt{x}\cos{x}}{x+2013}}\leq  {\frac{\sqrt{x}\cos{x}}{x}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$ but it diverges so i cant go any further. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}\,\cos x}{x+2013} = \frac{\sqrt{x}\,\cos x}{x} - \biggl(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+2013}\biggr)\sqrt{x}\,\cos x.$$

The convergence of the integral of the first summand (as an improper Riemann integral) is easily shown (think of alternating series), and the second summand is absolutely integrable.

Comment: I also managed to show using Dirichlete's test.

Comment: If you are familiar with Dirichlet's test, that works too, of course.  That also works for the original integrand (if you split the integral at $2013$ or work with a more general formulation of the criterion), since $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+a}$ is decreasing on $[a,+\infty)$.